# IIS application pool ignores Shutdown Time Limit (seconds) with c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

### Shutdown Time Limit (seconds) - problem

I have an asp.net web form application that needs to save in-memory Db on disc before it ends(triggered by recycling at specific time). The time for saving the db is now growing and it sometimes takes more than 5 minutes.

I have increased "Shutdown Time Limit (seconds)" time for my application pool to 10 minutes but it did not help. If IIS triggers recycling event or I do it manually it always finished after 5 minutes.

### Proof from log file

```
2016-04-20 19:03:44.1431 - INFO [9588]: Application_End
2016-04-20 19:03:44.1431 - INFO [9588]: Delay saving to total 444 seconds
2016-04-20 19:03:45.1462 - INFO [9588]: Delay 1 second passed
.
2016-04-20 19:08:45.1762 - INFO [9588]: Delay 301 second passed
```

**301 second is the last line from the log.**

In order to eliminate any side effects I have created a new empty asp.net web app.( .NET 4.5)  I use only simple method that logs every second a new line and I am able to reproduce the same behavior.

```c#
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using NLog;

namespace DemoApplicationLog
{
    internal static class Log
    {
        public static Logger Instance { get; private set; }
        static Log()
        {
            LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();

            Instance = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        }
    }

    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Log.Instance.Info("Application_End");
            DelaySavingBySeconds(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DelaySavingBySeconds"]);
        }

        private static void DelaySavingBySeconds(string interval)
        {
            Log.Instance.Info($"Delay saving to total {interval} seconds");

            var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DelaySavingBySeconds"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                interval = "0";
            }

            var intervalInSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(interval);

            foreach (var second in Enumerable.Range(1, intervalInSeconds))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Log.Instance.Info($"Delay {second} second passed");
            }

            Log.Instance.Info("Delaying passed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on:
win 7, IIS 7.5.7600.16385
win 2012R2, IIS 8.5.9600.16384

I have set up a new application pool with .NET CLR Version v4.0

### Facts I can reproduce

1. "Shutdown Time Limit" is ignored, if the value is greater than 5 minutes (300 sec.)
2. "Shutdown Time Limit" works fine, if the value is lesser than 5 minutes
3. If I change anything in the Web.config file and IIS recycle(caused by the change), application is *NOT* terminated after 5 minutes.

Is it IIS bug or what could be possibly wrong?

Thanks Petr

[The demo web app is available on github](https://github.com/vojtechovsky/DemoApplicationLogIssue)

Comment: did you happen to find a solution for this?

Comment: As today, I have not found any solution to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Like many developers I have had may share of IIS Pools shut downs, and Worker Process Recycling issues. Instead of tweaking any settings in IIS there are a couple of approaches that can keep the process alive as your save time gets longer and longer.

I will share something I have done on many sites to get rid of the headache of IIS recycles.

(1) One particular site I run a batch process in IIS in an ASP.NET Thread. It can run from 15 minutes to 1/2 hour.  In that particular case I will ping the URL of of the site every 10 minutes to keep the worker process alive.

(2) Another case, I developed interally facing sites and the users do not want to log out or get timed out. In this case place a hidden iFrame on the page, and have JavaScript post that page back every 15 minutes. This worker process will never shut down.  [It sounds like this example may work for you.](http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/2011/05/17/Stop-ASPNET-Session-Timeouts)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have no problem of keeping the worker alive.It is not the session level I have trouble with. My problem is to rely on the scheduled "Recycling" of IIS and finish the job during the specified time interval "Shutdown Time Limit" in the "Application_End" method. IMHO it should work. **I am very surprised nobody have  ever noticed it does not work.** What surprised me even more is the fact "Recycling" triggered by changing web.config **works** but not by the scheduled "Recycling". I am not a big fan of programming "scheduling" system when it is done already in IIS.